# Jupyter Notebook 500 Internal Server Error Attribute error module 'typing' has no attribute 'AsyncGenerator'

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to create and open notebook and I got

**500 : Internal Server Error**

and in my terminal I saw this
**AttributeError: module 'typing' has no attribute 'AsyncGenerator'**

[image]

```
Python version = 3.6    
Jupyter Notebook version = 6.1.6    
Windows 10
```

I had tried to upgrade notebook too using **pip install --upgrade jupyter** it did not help me.

Comment: Problem looks like about Python. Try to upgrade Python version.

Comment: @ishakO. Yeah I upgraded it to 3.6.5 and it started working.
but that is not the proper solution. what about 3.6.0 version?

Answer (score -1):

Try uninstalling whatever version of python you have. I had the exact same problem, so I uninstalled my python application, then reinstalled. I also had to upgrade my pip version to pip-21.0.1 using this command:

C:\Python\Python38\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

After that, I restarted my computer, opened up Jupyter from command prompt, and it worked.